# How to remove infinite scroll in javascript scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making three column layout template. Where i make two side bar fixed on screen with javascript scroll event as follow but i scroll down to view the content of the center div, there is infinite scroll although it reach the end of the content.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#left').css('top', $(this).scrollTop()+10 + "px");
    $('#exright').css('top', $(this).scrollTop()+100 + "px");
});
</script>
```

Comment: if you make the bars affix, you really **don't need** to use js, in fact, bootstrap provide you with a method at http://get.bootstrap.com/ else, you could use just `position: fixed` in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is Ok. I check it on the JSFiddle. I think you forgot to add position CSS in your code. Check out this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('#left').css('top', $(this).scrollTop()+10 + "px");
$('#exright').css('top', $(this).scrollTop()+100 + "px");
```

});

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/anikcse/ey4649k1/)